# Attachment is uploaded correctly, but returns wrong response

Tags: c#, asp-classic, image-upload

So I have this **C#** function that uploads files to a cms system.

```
    private void UploadFilesToRemoteUrl(string Link_To_ASP, string files)
    {
        WebClient wc = new WebClient();
        wc.UploadFile(Link_To_ASP, "post", files);

        Stream myStream = wc.OpenRead(Link_To_ASP);
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(myStream);
        MessageBox.Show(sr.ReadToEnd());
        myStream.Close();
    }
```

The **Link_To_ASP** parameter is calling a classic asp, that performs the request.

Here is the part of the asp that is making the upload (using ChestySoft component):

```
Set Upload = Server.CreateObject("csASPUpload32.Process")
```

**It works okay and the files are uploaded.**

Then I have this check up:

```
If Upload.FileQty > 0 Then
'Code with response info about the image
```

If I use a simple web form like this bellow I receive correct response:

```
<form action="Link_To_ASP">
    Select image to upload:
                <br>
                <br>
    <input type="file" name="file1" >
                <br>
                <br>
    <input type="submit" value="Upload" name="submit">
</form>
```

In this case the check up passes and **Upload.FileQty returns 1**, plus all the file info I need.

But when I use my C# function, it returns **Upload.FileQty = 0** (even though the upload is successful!) and I can't get the file info I need.

Why is this happening? What is the difference between the simple web form and my c# post request?

Comment: You should really post this in the support forums of whatever upload component you're using, or if private, contact whoever wrote it. We can't possibly debug and fix third party components. (Chances that someone using exact same component faced exactly the same problem are very low.)

Comment: Okay, thank you, i will do that :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that the problem it is **not** in the chestysoft component or the ASP, but in the C# request I'm having and more specifically - the encoding.

So I just changed this:

```
private void UploadFilesToRemoteUrl(string Link_To_ASP, string files)
{
    WebClient wc = new WebClient();
    wc.UploadFile(Link_To_ASP, "post", files);

    Stream myStream = wc.OpenRead(Link_To_ASP);
    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(myStream);
    MessageBox.Show(sr.ReadToEnd());
    myStream.Close();
}
```

into this:

```
private void UploadFilesToRemoteUrl(string Link_To_ASP, string files)
{
     WebClient wc = new WebClient();
     byte[] responseArray = wc.UploadFile(url,"POST", files);
     Console.WriteLine("\nAttachmentID:\n{0}",Encoding.ASCII.GetString(responseArray));
}
```

And now it works perfectly.